# Gas line sizing for a manifold system

Tags: natural-gas

So I thought I understood the charts for natural gas pipe sizing but now that I have added everything up I am confused. The gas line coming from the road to the meter is only 1” line. So it doesn't make sense to me to go bigger than 1” but if you add up my appliances they add up to 305000 and the farthest run would be about 50’ from the meter. (I should probably clarify I plan on running one line from the meter 30’ to a manifold then branching off the manifold for each appliance) That means I would need 1 1/4 for my first section of line to the manifold. But that's bigger than the line coming from the road. My plan was to use CSST for everything but it's sounding like I may be better of running 1 1/4” iron pipe to the manifold. Could someone help me understand this better?  Thanks.

Comment: So I assume 1 1/4” pipe is outside diameter? That is the size of the outlet on the meter hanger (loop is what I think the gas  company called it) so I guess that's the largest I can go. I am having a hard time finding 1 1/4” csst so I guess I will be running black pipe to the manifold.

Answer (score 1):

The line coming from the street is a much higher pressure. Once it hits your meter there is a regulator reducing pressure to about 7” from about 15# or so. The piping charts you are looking at should be for house pressure not line pressure.

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is a pressure-regulator before the meter, if so, it mean that it can deliver more gas then a low-pressure pipe, so using a bigger line after the meter is a good thing.